# An error have ocurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I was developing an app, where I make some api call using retrofit, and I get into the above title error. Regarding my expirience, I know is related with Retrofit is waiting a JSON, but get a String. I swear I'm parsing correctly the request model, which iis this:

UserModel.kt

```
data class UserModel(
    @SerializedName("info") val info: Info,
    @SerializedName("results") val results: List<Result>
)

data class Result(
    @SerializedName("cell") val cell: String,
    @SerializedName("dob") val dob: Dob,
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String,
    @SerializedName("gender") val gender: String,
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Id,
    @SerializedName("location") val location: Location,
    @SerializedName("login") val login: Login,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: Name,
    @SerializedName("nat") val nat: String,
    @SerializedName("phone") val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("picture") val picture: Picture,
    @SerializedName("registered") val registered: Registered
)

all the rest of class are the same struture, and I check the name are OK.
```

Regarding my Retrofit configuration:

ApiClient.kt

```
class ApiClient(
    private var baseUrl: String = Constants.BASE_URL,
    private val okHttpClientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder? = null,
    private val callFactory: Call.Factory? = null,
    private val converterFactory: Converter.Factory? = null,
) {
    private val apiAuthorizations = mutableMapOf<String, Interceptor>()
    var logger: ((String) -> Unit)? = null

    private val retrofitBuilder: Retrofit.Builder by lazy {
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .apply {
                if (converterFactory != null) {
                    addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                }
            }
    }

    private val clientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder by lazy {
        okHttpClientBuilder ?: defaultClientBuilder
    }

    private val defaultClientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder by lazy {
        OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(
                HttpLoggingInterceptor { message -> logger?.invoke(message) }
                    .apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
            )
    }

    init {
        normalizeBaseUrl()
    }

    /**
     * Adds an authorization to be used by the client
     *
     * @param authName Authentication name
     * @param authorization Authorization interceptor
     * @return ApiClient
     */
    fun addAuthorization(authName: String, authorization: Interceptor): ApiClient {
        if (apiAuthorizations.containsKey(authName)) {
            throw RuntimeException("auth name $authName already in api authorizations")
        }
        apiAuthorizations[authName] = authorization
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor(authorization)
        return this
    }

    fun setLogger(logger: (String) -> Unit): ApiClient {
        this.logger = logger
        return this
    }

    fun <S> createService(serviceClass: Class<S>): S {
        val usedCallFactory = this.callFactory ?: clientBuilder.build()
        return retrofitBuilder.callFactory(usedCallFactory).build().create(serviceClass)
    }

    private fun normalizeBaseUrl() {
        if (!baseUrl.endsWith("/")) {
            baseUrl += "/"
        }
    }

    private inline fun <T, reified U> Iterable<T>.runOnFirst(callback: U.() -> Unit) {
        for (element in this) {
            if (element is U) {
                callback.invoke(element)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I inject it with dagger:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class AppModule {
    private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAPi():ApiRandomUser{
        return ApiClient(
            baseUrl = Constants.BASE_URL,
            converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(),
            okHttpClientBuilder = httpClient
        ).createService(ApiRandomUser::class.java)
    }
}
```

As you can check i'm using Gson, which I read may cause error like this, but I need add the  ".setLenient()" property to avoid another error.

Regarding the API class:

```
interface ApiRandomUser {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("/")
    suspend fun getResults():UserModel
}
```

And my BASE_URL is this:

```
 const val BASE_URL: String = "https://randomuser.me/api"
```

So, I knoow there can be several reason this error happens (Malformed models, GSON configuration, url error...), but I'd say I not doing any of this.

What Am I missing?

Thanks in advance !

[EDIT]

Okey, so after a little debugging, I release that what I'm reciving from the API is an HTML, so that the crash. The code itself, if the API return a JSON structure it's works

Comment: Check the JSON string you are actually receiving. I bet it starts with `"`, not with `{`.

Comment: When I debug the method of the api I get the exception, I don't take to see the response. Anyway, If it's that the case, how should I change the code to make it work? Should I expect a String?

Comment: That's impossible to tell without knowing what you are receiving